# How to adjust window border size

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a window, which I want it to behave like a toggle button. Once clicked it will add 4px border and clicking after will make the border disappear. I figured how to make the window behave like a toggle button using `BS_PUSHLIKE` and `Button_SetCheck()` but can't seem to figure out how to adjust the border size for this window.

Thanks to all who take their time to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use [MoveWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow) to resize the window, and then draw the border yourself, like this,

[image]

Draw a borderless window first:

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      100, 100, 800, 600, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
LONG lStyle = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
lStyle &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU);
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle);
```

Then handle the window border in the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message:

```
int num = 0;
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {     
        RECT rcWind;
        HDC dc = GetDC(hWnd);
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rcWind);     
        if (num >= 0)
        {        
            num--;
            RECT rcClient;
            MoveWindow(hWnd, rcWind.left - 4, rcWind.top - 4, 8 + rcWind.right - rcWind.left, 8 + rcWind.bottom - rcWind.top, TRUE);
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);
            HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 4, RGB(255, 128, 1));
            HGDIOBJ hOldPen = SelectObject(dc, hPen);
            Rectangle(dc, rcClient.left, rcClient.top, rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom);
            DeleteObject(hPen);
        }   
        else if (num < 0)
        {
            MoveWindow(hWnd, rcWind.left + 4, rcWind.top + 4, rcWind.right - rcWind.left - 8, rcWind.bottom - rcWind.top - 8, TRUE);
            num++;
        }
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Painting makes sense but my windows are child windows and they already have a color, using this method how am I going to paint the window in two different colors?

Comment: @userover8k Considering [Subclassing Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview). You can create a window procedure for each child window, and then handle their `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` messages separately. Note: The position of the child window is relative to the parent window, not the upper left corner of the screen, so you need to rearrange some codes.